Error while assembling a masm x86 code (using masm615)
playlevel1 MACRO
mov ax,01
int 33h
 mov si,15
 .repeat
    mov ah,05
    int 33h
    mov ax,0
    
    .if bx==0
        mov clickedatx,cx
        mov clickedaty,dx
        add ax,1
    .endif
    .if bx==0 && ax==1
        .if cx+60 == clickedatx || cx-60 == clickedatx || dx+60 == clickedaty || dx-60 == clickedaty
            clicked_Candy
            print_a_shape 0,clickedatx,clickedatx
            mov clickedatx,cx
            mov clickedaty,dx
            clicked_Candy
            print_a_shape 0,clickedatx,clickedatx
            add score,5
        .endif
    .endif  
mov bx,1
 .until si==0

endm
This part of the code snippet gives errors (linked in the image)  image Only the macros in this code snippet are giving errors
note: code is for a candy crush game and this snippet is stored in a library

Verify what arguments print_a_shape expects. From the error message it probably does not like the 0. Make sure score is defined. Next time do not post errors as picture. Provide and mark the lines referenced in the messages.

print_a_shape MACRO num,ro,col
.IF (num==1) || (num==2)
PRINT_I ro,col
.ELSEIF (num==3) || (num==4)
PRINT_MUSHROOM ro,col
.ELSEIF (num==5) || (num==6)
PRINT_PLUS ro,col
.ELSEIF (num==7) || (num==7)
PRINT_SQUARE ro,col
.ELSE
PRINT_BOMB ro,col
.ENDIF
endm
this is the code for print_a_shape macro can you see if there is something wrong with it

That should take a 0 apparently. Does it work if you comment out the two invocations of print_a_shape?

Is it deliberate that you have the same test twice in: .ELSEIF (num==7) || (num==7) ?
